# C++: vector.erase instance of a class with const int gives "attempting to reference a deleted function" error C2280

Tags: c++, class, oop, vector, constants

C++: vector.erase instance of a class with const int gives "attempting to reference a deleted function" error C2280

Class B has a const int attribute `const_int`. If I make a vector of B instances and then delete an element from that vector - I get the following error:

```
Error   C2280   'B &B::operator =(const B &)': attempting to reference a deleted function   VectorTest  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\prof\vc\tools\msvc\14.10.25017\include\xutility 2534
```

If I remove the `const` keyword - the error disappears.
How do I fix it while keeping my attribute `const_int` constant?
Why does this error appear, is vector.erase() trying to call some function from class B?
Thank you!

B.h

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class B
{
private:
    const int const_int;
public:
    B(int const_int_input);
    ~B();
};
```

B.cpp

```
#include "B.h"

B::B(int const_int_input) : const_int(const_int_input)
{
}


B::~B()
{
}
```

Source.cpp

```
#include "B.h"

int main() {
    vector<B> test;
    test.push_back(B(1));
    test.erase(test.begin());
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `std::vector<>::erase` need to be able to assign elements of the vector to collapse the space (created by the erase operation).  As class `B` contains a constant the assignment operator is automatically declared as deleted by the compiler as it is not possible to assign to a constant value. See __Type requirements__ http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase

Answer (score 4, accepted):

according to the [`std::vector::erase`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase) documentation:

> Type requirements
>   - T must meet the requirements of MoveAssignable.

So in order to use `std::vector::erase`, you need to either have a move-assignment operator ( `T& operator = (T&&)` ) , or a copy-assignment operator (`T& operator = (const T&)`). since you supplied your own constructor, the compiler didn't generate any assignment operator.

The logic behind this requirement is that the vector tries to fill the gap caused by `erase` by the rest of the variables. it tries to move the elements right to the erased elements in order to fill the hole `erase` makes.

Since your class has `const int`, that means you don't actually want your object to be assigned, because `const_int` is.. const. you explicitly said you don't want this variable to be re-assigned.

in this case, you can create an array of pointers to B:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<B>> vector;
vector.emplace_back(std::make_unique<B>(1));
vector.erase(vector.begin());
```

another possibility is to lost the `const` on `const_int` and provide move-assignment oeprator.

Comment: Holy shit, I can't imagine how long it would have taken me to figure out that that little const var in my class was the culprit. Really appreciate your explanation!

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [std::list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) (doubly linked list, if not needed indexion by ints) which does not do such movement of elements, [std::set](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) (good for insertions and deletions) or [std::unordered_set](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set) (if the order does not matter, the most efficient of the 3 alternatives mentioned).